# Does the monero gui client use the GPU to sync with the blockchain?

Tags: monerod

I can't tell whether it is trying to use my GPU as well or if it is only using the CPU. I've got it synching on a rig with 3 HD7950s on windows 7. Want to mine something while it's synching if it is not using the GPUs. The hashrate reported for 1.41 mh/s which makes me think it's using the GPUs since there's no way my CPU could ever do that. It's been over a day and my i7 with 9gb of RAM is still only 50% of the way through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (v0.10.3.1), the daemon (*monerod*) and the clients (*monero-wallet-cli*, *monero-wallet-rpc* and *monero-wallet-gui*) only use the CPU for their computations.

Only some programs dedicated to pool mining use GPUs.

Comment: thank you, I am well aware of using the various GPU mining programs to pool mine, I just wasn't sure if the actual monerod/client used my CPU or GPU. Couldn't find an explicit answer anywhere thank you very much!